# Usage of the word Console

Tags: word-usage, verbs, word-in-context

Console means to comfort someone at a time of grief or disappointment. I wrote a sentence in one of the paragraphs

> Everybody knew it was written by Sam and they came to him turn by turn to console.

Is this usage correct?

Comment: I'd prefer 'they came turn by turn to console him'.

Comment: @Micheal Harvey...I was also thinking about it. But I want to know if there is something wrong in my sentence.

Comment: Your suggestion is unusual and awkward, which is what I was trying to tell you.

Comment: Your definition says '...to comfort _someone_'.

Comment: Or "...  they came to him turn by turn to give consolation" or "...  they came to him turn by turn giving consolation".